# encrypting my files and delivering

Tags: fedora

Are there ways to encrypt my hd or user (fedora) and host a webserver meanwhile?

I mean, having my user files encrypted while delivering non-encrypted files with the webserver or something like this.

Trying to protect my files and delivering files to clients, nothing illegal in anyway.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problems with this. Encrypting the files provides 'at-rest' encryption of those files, and so long as the encrypted partition is mounted correctly there is nothing stopping it from being served up by a web-server. Or FTP. Or Dropbox.

Comment: I'd kiss you if you were here.